# Actual values of smooth/spline curve in xyplot R

Tags: r, smoothing, spline

I would like to obtain the actual values of the smoothed curve. Precisely, values lying on the smoothed curve so that corresponding values of x and y are known given the point on the curve.

I have discrete data and I fit smoothed curve via `xyplot(....,type="spline",...)`

The smoothed curve looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to fit polynomial so that `y~x+x^2+x^3...+x^15` so that if x is given, we obtain the "precise" value of y. However, I'm not happy fitting the polynomial etc. What other way would be to obtain the y-axis and x-axis values by moving only on the curve?

Comment: Well, fit explicitly (e.g., using `spline` or `smooth.spline` or `loess` or ...) and use `predict` as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation, `?xyplot`, points you to `panel.xyplot` and then to `panel.spline`, which returns the model used.

```
r <- panel.spline(x,y)
predict(r, 3)$y
```